# Cubase 7 - I can't find the timestamp for each sample

Tags: cubase

In Cubase 5 I used to be able to click on a sample and details would appear showing the start time of the sample, the length etc

This option appears to have disappeared in Cubase 7. It used to appear in the toolbar (under the File Edit Project etc). I tried right clicking and Show All but it doesn't appear.

I'm sure it is there, but my Google searches have not returned anything, possibly due to incorrect search phrases.

So, I'd like to click on a sample, for example on the Chorus of my song a violin plays. I'd like to click on the sample to realise it starts at 0:3:53:686.

I no longer have Cubase 5 and can't provide my own screen shot, but I did find a blurry image else where:

[image]

Does any one know what it is called and how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent ages looking for this and typically I find the answer after I post the question.

It is called Info Line, screen shot to help:

[image]

Click the icon by the red arrow to bring up the dialog box.